# How to save json object received from ajax request to postgreSQL in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to save a JSON object into Note object. But getting this error: `InterfaceError-Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.`

#### index.js

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/notes/{{note.id}}/update",
   data: {
      content: editor.getContents(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
   }
});
```

#### views.py

```py
def update_view(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = Note.objects.get(pk=id)
        note.content = request.POST['content']
        note.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

#### models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Note(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = JSONField()
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shown enough information here. But probably you need to parse the raw JSON before passing it to the model:

```
    note.content = json.loads(request.POST['content'])
```